# SQL Server Update sub query with formula not quite right

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (table1) of names and their frequencies

```
Name-----Frequency

Mike-------0.56

Fred-------0.30

Nancy------0.14
```

and a Cartesian product (table2) where the names are paired in two columns and a third column where I would like to sum the frequencies from table1 by matching the names in the first two columns back to table1.

```
Name1-------Name2------sum

Mike--------Fred     

Mike--------Nancy

Fred--------Nancy
```

I want to update the sum column of table2 using the frequencies in table 1 with a subquery in the update for the matching names (Or so this is how I imagine I need to do it).  If there is a better way please let me know.

I have:

```
UPDATE table2
SET sum = (SELECT dbo.table1.Frequency WHERE Name1 = dbo.table1.Name) +
          (SELECT dbo.table1.Frequency WHERE Name2 = dbo.table1.Name)
FROM table1
```

I get a table full of NULLs instead of the frequency sums.
Am I going about this the right way?  Am I totally missing how to do this and there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Storing aggregate data like this on every row is a clear sign that there are some serious normalization issues going on.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this.  I’m compiling a large database of equation results from a finite set of frequencies to index all possible results to make large sets of calculations from them as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating from a join like this:

```
update a 
set a.sum=isnull(b.frequency,0)+isnull(c.frequency,0)
from  table2  a
left join table1 b  on a.name1=b.name 
left join table1 c  on a.name2=c.name
```

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  I still need so much to learn.  I need to understand these joins and alias better.

Comment: OK great - feel free to reach out anytime if you need help

Answer (score 2):

Your method is fine.  If all names match:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET sum = (SELECT f.frequency FROM dbo.table1.Frequency f WHERE t2.Name1 = f.Name) +
              (SELECT f.frequency FROM dbo.table1.Frequency f WHERE t2.Name2 = f.Name)
    FROM table2 t2;
```

If they don't, then use `isnull()` (or `coalesce()`, but `isnull()` is more efficient):

```
UPDATE t2
    SET sum = isnull( (SELECT f.frequency FROM dbo.table1.Frequency f WHERE t2.Name1 = f.Name), 0) +
              isnull( (SELECT f.frequency FROM dbo.table1.Frequency f WHERE t2.Name2 = f.Name), 0)
    FROM table2 t2;
```

Comment: Ill have a look at this in a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: `ifNull()` == `isNull()` in SQL Server. ;-)

Comment: It appears to me that the isnull() makes all the difference but given the result I was getting, I would think the return should be 0.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Dan . . . Adding a value to `NULL` results in `NULL`.